# C# WinSCP .NET assembly: How to upload multiple files asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, winscp, winscp-net

I am using WinSCP .NET assembly for uploading files. I want to upload multiple files asynchronous way. I have created a method but it works as single upload.

```
public class UploadingData {

    private SessionOptions _sessionOptions;
    private Session _session;

    //connection etc

    private void OnConnected() {

        foreach (var fileInfo in localFilesList)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UploadFilesAsync(fileInfo));
        }
    }

    private async Task UploadFilesAsync(string file) {

        string remoteFilePath = _session.TranslateLocalPathToRemote(file, @"/", "/test_data_upload");
        var uploading = _session.PutFiles(file, remoteFilePath, false);

        //When Done

        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    }
}
```

Please suggest me correct way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The API of the [`Session` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session) can be used from a single thread only. If you use it from multiple threads, it will block.

So if you need parallel transfers, you have to create a separate `Session` instance for each thread.

```
private async Task UploadFilesAsync(string file)
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        session.Open(_sessionOptions);
        string remoteFilePath =
            RemotePath.TranslateLocalPathToRemote(file, @"/", "/test_data_upload");
        session.PutFiles(file, remoteFilePath, false).Check();
    }

    ...
}
```

See also WinSCP article [Automating transfers in parallel connections over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers) with code examples for C# and PowerShell.

Note that you should not use more than few sessions/threads (about 4). With more sessions, you will hardly get better throughput.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BackgroundWorker class like this:

```
        string[] images = new string[50];
        foreach (var path in images)
        {
            BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
            //50 independently async Threads
            w.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args) 
            {
                Upload(args.Argument.ToString());
            };
            w.RunWorkerAsync(path);
        }
```

Comment: If need I to upload thousands of files then there will be thousands of background workers. is it fine for application and CPU?

Comment: Using thousands of theads in one application is not good practise. So that, the more your application has threads, the less quota time each threads executing in. You can seperate thousands of files by 50-50 and upload each parts sequentially with 50 async thread, for example.

Comment: As @Martin said Session class will put all the files in queue.